# navigation.navigate() doesn't work at the same time as setState() in react native

Tags: react-native

I've created a navbar at the bottom of a react native app which functions perfectly fine until I add in functionality to change the colors of the icons and text that are clicked on.

I can get the navigation to work without the color changes, and I can get the color changes to function smoothly without the navigation.navigate(), but I can't do both at the same time for some reason.

When I have both together, the navigation.navigate works but the color is behind by at least 1 click.

I thought I could trigger the color change first by updating the tab state then triggering useEffect to navigate to the clicked tab, but that doesn't work.

I tried context but didn't have any luck and that feels unnecessary for such simple functionality. Figure I must be missing something obvious that I'm not seeing.

````
  import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
  import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

  const stylesCustom = StyleSheet.create({
    navItemView: {
      position: 'relative',
      bottom: 10,
      display: 'flex',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    colorPink: {
      color: 'pink'
    }
  });

  const MainContent = () => {  
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [tab, setTab] = useState('Home')
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(loaded) {
      navigation.navigate(tab);
    }
    setLoaded(true);
  }, [tab])

  return (
    <View style={[ stylesCustom.mainContainer ]}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setTab('Home')}>
        <View style={[stylesCustom.navItemView]}>
          <Icon name='home-outline' type='material-community' color={`${tab === 'Home' ? 'pink' : '#757781'}`} size={35} />
          <Text style={tab === 'Home' ? [ styles.fontSmall, styles.textGray, styles.mt5, stylesCustom.colorPink] : [styles.fontSmall, styles.textGray, styles.mt5 ]}>Home</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setTab('Grow')}>
        <View style={[stylesCustom.navItemView]}>
          <Icon name='flower-outline' type='material-community' color={`${tab === 'Grow' ? 'pink' : '#757781'}`} size={35} />
          <Text style={tab === 'Grow' ? [ styles.fontSmall, styles.textGray, styles.mt5, stylesCustom.colorPink] : [styles.fontSmall, styles.textGray, styles.mt5 ]}>Grow</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setTab('Events')}>
        <View style={[stylesCustom.navItemView]}>
          <Icon name='calendar-clock' type='material-community' color={`${tab === 'Events' ? 'pink' : '#757781'}`} size={35} />
          <Text style={tab === 'Events' ? [ styles.fontSmall, styles.textGray, styles.mt5, stylesCustom.colorPink] : [styles.fontSmall, styles.textGray, styles.mt5 ]}>Events</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>     
  );
}```
````

Comment: Why don't you use the tab navigator built by react-navigation? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation

Comment: I'm already using a drawer navigator and can't use both unfortunately @Bojke

Comment: You can nest them. Check out this article: https://dev.to/easybuoy/combining-stack-tab-drawer-navigations-in-react-native-with-react-navigation-5-da

Comment: Thanks @Bojke! I'll give this a try

Comment: Here's a better article I found for anyone else struggling with this. https://shreyasnisal.medium.com/multiple-navigators-in-react-navigation-5-883a415187a0